# Eclipse Neon - Content Assist Timing Out

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist, eclipse-neon

I've been an Eclipse user for years and the content assist has always worked great.  Since I transitioned to Eclipse Neon, I have been having issues with the content assist.  Content assist hangs for several seconds then I get the following error:

[image: error message]

My colleagues are using Eclipse Neon as well and do not have this issue.  Are there any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

I have messed around with my content assist settings after experiencing this issue trying to cut out some of the overhead, but that hasn't helped.  The current state is shown below.

[image: settings]

[image: advanced settings]

One other note - I also tried adding the following to my eclipse.ini, but this did not help either.

> -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ui.codeAssistTimeout=60000

Comment: I suggest you look at the eclipse bugtracker and if you don't find something that matches your problem, raise a bug.

Comment: Try to disable *Code Recommenders* proposals.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by changing my settings in Window > Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions.  When I turned off Subwords-Completion Processor my content assist was working well.

Comment: I had the same problem in STS version 3.8.3 and your answer solved it.

Comment: Thanks! This solve my problem in Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

Comment: Worked nice to me in STS. Thank you

Comment: This solution also works in the Photon Release (4.8.0)

Comment: Worked for me too in Eclipse 2018-09

Comment: I just tried this in Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3) and every time I restart Eclipse Subwords-Completion Processor is enabled again.

Comment: I'm facing the same as Janne Oksannen. Every time I restart, that check is enabled again.